# text distortion on ubuntu after resuming from suspend

Tags: suspend, fonts

[image]

any suggestions? as the photo shows the font in certain applications on UI is partial or missing totally. I have experienced this on at least 2 different versions of ubuntu 14.04 (as I remember) and now 15.04.